# Why do scatter.smooth from package stats and geom_smooth from package ggplot2 give different results?

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

This is the loess smoothing curve in base r

```
dat <- data.frame(RT = c(151, 160, 168, 169, 172, 175, 189, 279),
              IQ = c(123, 121, 115, 110, 105, 103, 100, 120))
with(dat, scatter.smooth(IQ, RT, span = 0.8))
```

[image]

And this is the loess curve produced with ggplot:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = IQ, y = RT)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = stats::loess, se = F, span = 0.8)
```

[image]

Why are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `scatter.smooth()` does not use the default `loess()` arguments, whereas `geom_smooth()` does. If you provide the method arguments that are default in `scatter.smooth()` to the ggplot2 method, they produce very similar results.

```r
dat <- data.frame(RT = c(151, 160, 168, 169, 172, 175, 189, 279),
                  IQ = c(123, 121, 115, 110, 105, 103, 100, 120))
with(dat, scatter.smooth(IQ, RT, span = 0.8))

library(ggplot2)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = IQ, y = RT)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess", se = F, span = 0.8,
              method.args = list(degree = 1, family = "symmetric"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>